# How to change default shell of OpenWrt?

Tags: linux, openwrt, fish, busybox, ash

The default shell of OpenWrt is `ash`, but I would like to change it to `fish`.

When I ran `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish` (the absolute path of `fish`), it returned `-ash: chsh: not found`.

The I changed the first line of `/etc/passwd` from:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash`

to:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/fish`

I could't login again (wrong password), and the system log showed:

`authpriv.warn dropbear[14288]: User 'root' has invalid shell, rejected`

---

Is there any other way to change the default shell?

(By the way, I am using [a popular fork of OpenWrt](https://github.com/coolsnowwolf/lede) instead of [the official](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt), but it doesn't seem to be the reason of this problem)

Comment: Did you add /usr/bin/fish to /etc/shells ?

Comment: Add `/usr/bin/fish` to `/etc/shells` works!

Comment: This is a really bad idea. If you're opening an interactive shell on your router so often that you feel compelled to changing the default shell, rather than just typing `exec fish`, something is wrong.

Comment: @KurtisRader May I ask why using your routers shell a lot is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`chsh -s /usr/bin/fish` is correct.
But openwrt doesn't have chsh command installed.
You need to run
`opkg install shadow-chsh` first to install the chsh command.
Then run
`chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`
Finally, run
`echo $SHELL` to see if the replacement is successful.

Note that the above operations require root privileges to run.

Sorry for my poor English, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this. You can either:

### Add `/usr/bin/fish` to `/etc/shells`

This solution is provided by [@glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) above in the comments.

Or:

### Replacing `dropbear` by `openssh-server`

I've figured out another way: if you happen to have `openssh-server` installed, I would recommend you to [use it as default following this tutorial](https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/inbox/replacingdropbearbyopensshserver).

---

And remember to change the first line of /etc/passwd to:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/fish`